# How do I access the template color inside an article?

Tags: php, css, twitter-bootstrap, joomla

I'm fairly new to Joomla, using version 3.3.6 with the default protostar template (based on bootstrap). I'm using the [Sourcerer plugin](http://www.nonumber.nl/extensions/sourcerer) to insert PHP code into my articles.

Now I want to access the template color to style the border of a table. Inside the `index.php` I can just use `$this->params->get('templateColor')`. However, inside the article there is no object context defined. I have had a look at the [variables and objects that are defined in sourcerer](http://www.nonumber.nl/extensions/sourcerer/faqs#12_What-variables-objects-does-Sourcerer-have-ready-for-use). So far without success.

Or is there another (better) method of dynamically using template colors inside the editor?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use the below code for template-color

```
$app    = JFactory::getApplication();
$params = $app->getTemplate(true)->params;

$color  = $params->get('templateColor');
```

Comment: @user1 - It doesn't matter if it's already defined. You should always define it yourself, just to be on the safe side. I've known some extension developers to use `$mainframe` instead of `$app` ;)

Answer (score 0):

Nick's answer is correct. However, I found out it's easier and probably better to just create a css class

```
.templateColorBorder {
    border: 2px solid <?php echo $this->params->get('templateColor'); ?>;
}
```

inside `index.php`. That way I can just edit the article using the normal html editor and assign this class to the cells/tables I want to have a colored border and don't even need any PHP code inside the article.

```
<td class="templateColorBorder">
```